# Subcategory before parent category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a category named Z and a subcategory named A.

In my function, I am using this to get category Z (Parent)

```
$category[0]->slug
```

The problem is that subcategory A is set as [0] because it is alphabetical order. Z is the parent category, so Z should be [0]. I don't get why it is in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use this wordpress function to do that:

```
//Load data for your Sub-Category
$subcategory = get_category("A");

//from Sub-Category get parent ID ( Z )
$parent_category_ID = $subcategory->parent;

//load object for Parent-Category ( Z )
$objet_parent_category = get_category($parent_category);

//Get the Parent Category slug
$parent_name = $parent_name->slug; // to get name: ->name
```

I hope help you!